# how to swap data between two columns based on the data type? [R]

Tags: r

ds <- read.csv(file="~/Desktop/abalone.csv)

```
Sex  Length
 M     12.1
 F     11.2
12.1    F
 I     11.2
12.1   11.2
11.2    I
```

The dataset contains two columns which are sex and Length. The sex column contains three values which are "F" (Female), "M" (Male) and "I" (infant). The dataset has been modified and has several issues which I need to solve. I need to solve the following problems

1. misfielded values (need help for this question)
2. Invalid values(solved)

My idea to solve the misfielded values is to swap the data between two columns based on the value in Length. let say if the value in Length is "F", "M" and "I", then swap the data with Sex. I really have no idea how to swap the data between these two column based on the value in length.

```
swap_if <-function (ds$Sex, ds$Length, missing = NA){
  a <- ds$Length == "M"
  b <- ds$Length == "F"
  c <- ds$Length == "I"}

swap_if(ds$Sex, ds$Length)
```

but this cannot work. can someone help me with this. thank you so much

After that, I need to remove the invalid values. the fifth row first column has an invalid values as the value of Sex must be 'F', 'M' and 'I'.

```
#remove wrong format /invalid data in sex column
ds <- ds[!str_detect(ds$Sex, '([0-9])'), ]
ds$Sex <- as.factor(ds$Sex)
```

^ this code can remove the row with invalid / wrong format values.

Comment: Welcome. What do you get when you put `str(dataset)` (or whatever you named it)?

Comment: This might not be what you asked, but ... while it's not too hard, I recommend you *don't* try to fix this problem, instead fixing whatever method you used to import the data like this. If it's in a spreadsheet like that, go after whatever (or whomever) put it in into the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Despite what I recommended (fixing the source of the problem), here's a method for trying to recover.

```r
column <- grepl("^[.0-9]+$", dat[,1])
column
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
dat2 <- data.frame(Sex = dat[cbind(seq_len(nrow(dat)),1+column)], Length = dat[cbind(seq_len(nrow(dat)),2-column)])
dat2$Length <- as.numeric(dat2$Length)
dat2
#   Sex Length
# 1   M   12.2
# 2   F   14.1
# 3   M   14.6
# 4   F    9.0
# 5   L   12.1
# 6   M   10.1
# 7   F   11.0
# 8   M   11.9
```

A tidyverse option:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(
    swap    = grepl("[^.[:digit:]]", Length), 
    Length2 = if_else(swap, Sex, Length), 
    Sex2    = if_else(swap, Length, Sex)
  ) %>%
  transmute(
    Sex    = Sex2, 
    Length = as.numeric(Length2)
  )
#   Sex Length
# 1   M   12.2
# 2   F   14.1
# 3   M   14.6
# 4   F    9.0
# 5   L   12.1
# 6   M   10.1
# 7   F   11.0
# 8   M   11.9
```

Data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(Sex = c("M", "F", "M", "9", "L", "10.1", "11", 
"M"), Length = c("12.2", "14.1", "14.6", "F", "12.1", "M", "F", 
"11.9")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution which works with `tidyverse`. It creates a little helper column which will be deleted at the end.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# create the inverse of `%in%`
`%!in%` = Negate(`%in%`)

df %>% 
  # create a helper column, will be deleted
  mutate(help = Sex) %>% 
  mutate(Sex = case_when(
    Sex  %!in% c('L', 'M', 'F') ~ Length,
    TRUE ~ Sex
  )) %>% 
  mutate(Length = case_when(
    Length %in% c('L', 'M', 'F') ~ help,
    TRUE ~ Length
  )) %>% 
  # delete helper column
  select(-help)
#>   Sex Length
#> 1   M   12.2
#> 2   F   14.1
#> 3   M   14.6
#> 4   F      9
#> 5   L   12.1
#> 6   M   10.1
#> 7   F     11
#> 8   M   11.9
```

Comment: hi, I have modified my question. I want to swap the column based on the value in "Length" column. If the value in the length column is "M", "F" and "I" then swap the data with the data in "Sex" column. I tried to use ur method but it can't work.

Comment: I think it would have been the better way you ask a new question. It will difficult for future readers, to follow the discussion here, if you move the target of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a for loop with an if-then to check if the character variable can safely be converted to a numeric. If so, it belongs in `length`.

```
sex = c('M','F', 'M', 9, 'L', 10.1, 11, 'M')
length = c(12.2, 14.1, 14.6, 'F', 12.1, 'M', 'F', 11.9)

df = data.frame(sex, length)
str(df)

df$sex.c = 0
df$length.c = 0

for (i in 1:length(df$sex)){
  if (!is.na(as.numeric(df$sex[i]))){
    df$sex.c[i] = df$length[i]
    df$length.c[i] = df$sex[i]
  } else {
    df$sex.c[i] = df$sex[i]
    df$length.c[i] = df$length[i]
  }
}

df$sex = df$sex.c
df$length = df$length.c

df = df[,1:2]
```

Note that this creates a `NAs introduced by coercion` warning. If that bothers you then you can suppress them by altering the for loop as follows:

```
for (i in 1:length(df$sex)){
  if (suppressWarnings(!is.na(as.numeric(df$sex[i])))){
    df$sex.c[i] = df$length[i]
    df$length.c[i] = df$sex[i]
  } else {
    df$sex.c[i] = df$sex[i]
    df$length.c[i] = df$length[i]
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use ur method but it can't work. my dataset has 4177 rows and 7 columns. I only want to swap the data between sex and length. I want to swap the data if the value in length column is "F", "M" or 'I" then swap the data with sex column. I have modified my question

Comment: @KwaiSheng You would only need to modify the column calls to account for the extra columns you have (maybe use a `-` operator to delete columns `sex.c` and `length.c`). A for loop isn't the most efficient, but you shouldn't run into any issues with just 4177 rows.

Comment: What do you get for the structure of your dataframe (i.e. `str(ds)`)?

Comment: str(ds) Length = factors and the sex = factors